# Reading CSV line by line using OpenCSV and FifoBuffer

Tags: java, opencsv

I am reading a CSV file and using OpenCSV to read it and CircularFifoBuffer to split the data into columns and assign the value from each column to a string.  This works fine for reading a specific row in the csv file, however I wish to read the csv file line by line starting at the beginning and working downwards to the final row.

Then each time a row is read the string values will be compared and provided a given condition is satisfied the next row will be read.

I can handle all of the above bar processing the CSV data line by line.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Directly from [the FAQ](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read):

> If you want to use an Iterator style pattern, you might do something like this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```

> Or, if you might just want to slurp the whole lot into a List, just call readAll()...

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
List myEntries = reader.readAll();
```

> which will give you a List of String[] that you can iterate over. If all else fails, check out the Javadoc.

Comment: So your suggesting to read each line and import it into the FifoBuffer, process it and then move to the next line?